# Копирование/перенос при имени файла более 260 символов (c#)

Tags: c#

Как в C# реализуется копирование/перенос файла, если конечное имя файла длиннее 260 символов?

Использование `FileInfo` выдает `PathTooLongException`. Но если этот же файл перенести файловым менеджером (FAR, TC, проводник), то все нормально.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747132/pathtoolongexception-c-sharp-4-5

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Для закрытия вопроса*.
т.к. будет работать в основном на старой Windows 7 (не используются фишки NET 4.6.2 и Windows 10), воспользовался импортом Win32:

```
[DllImport(Kernel32, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);
```

Вызываю через:

```
public static bool MoveFile(string existingFileName, string newFileName)
{
   return Win32Native.MoveFileEx(string.Concat(Prefix, existingFileName), string.Concat(Prefix, newFileName), MoveFileFlags.CopyAllowed | MoveFileFlags.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

Спасибо Sergio, VladD.